# Simple example on how to use Websockets between Client and Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am new to websockets and just trying to get a handle of how to listen to a message from a client browser from the server and vice-versa.

I'm using a Node.js/Express setup and just want to be able to firstly listen for any messages from the client.

I've been looking at this https://github.com/websockets/ws library and have tried the examples but am not able to get this working within my localhost environment.

I'm also not clear what I need to look out for, when I'm listening for a message.

What code do I use on the client, i.e. url + port and what code do I use on the server?

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost/path', {
  perMessageDeflate: false
});
```

Comment: websocket servers are listening for messages from clients (and viceversa), not the backend itself. What you want is some kind of error handling framework (depending on which lib throws the error it might implement onerror callback handlers)

Comment: The title asks for one thing and the body asks for a completely different thing

Comment: @Adelin Thanks for pointing that out. Have edited my original post.

Answer (score 4):

Using websockets directly might be troublesome, it's advised you use a framework to abstract this layer, so they can easily fallback to other methods when not supported in the client. For example, this is a direct implementation using Express js and Websockets directly. This example also allows you to use the same server for HTTP calls.

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const app = express();

//initialize a simple http server
const server = http.createServer(app);

//initialize the WebSocket server instance
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {

    //connection is up, let's add a simple simple event
    ws.on('message', (message) => {

        //log the received message and send it back to the client
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        ws.send(`Hello, you sent -> ${message}`);
    });

    //send immediatly a feedback to the incoming connection    
    ws.send('Hi there, I am a WebSocket server');
});

//start our server
server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${server.address().port} :)`);
});
```

For the client, you can do something like this:

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000')
ws.onopen = () => {
  console.log('ws opened on browser')
  ws.send('hello world')
}

ws.onmessage = (message) => {
  console.log(`message received`, message.data)
}
```

Like i have mentioned above, it is advised that you use a mature framework for websockets. Should your app be minimal and not need scaling, you can use any open source library, with [socket.io](https://socket.io) being the most popular.

However, if you are talking about implementing this to be used at production level, you should know that the open source solutions do not allow for scalability, failover, message ordering etc. In that case, you’ll have to implement a realtime platform as a service tool.

Comment: Have tried your example but on the client side as part of your ws.onmessage console log, I am receiving the output: message received [object MessageEvent] - what is this and what should have actually returned from the server as I don't think I am getting the correct message? Furthermore, in your server code, I believe all you "ws.on/send" should actually be "WebSocket.on/send"

Comment: This is because the message variable is an object and was displayed in a string.

you would need to access `message.data` to get the message that was actually sent. Updated the code to show that

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, `socket.io` is a backend/frontend library that uses `websocket` but also has a number of fallbacks if the client browser does not support websocket. The example below works with `ws` backend.

**Server**

```
const WS = require('ws')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

const wss = new WS.Server({
  port: PORT
}, () => console.log(`ws server live on ${PORT}`))

const errHandle = (err) => {
  if(err) throw err
}

wss.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('something connected')

  socket.send('you are connected', errHandle)

  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log(`socket sent ${data}`)

    socket.send('message received', errHandle)
  })
})
```

**client (browser)**

```
(() => {
  const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')
  ws.onopen = () => {
    console.log('ws opened on browser')
    ws.send('hello world')
  }

  ws.onmessage = (message) => {
    console.log(`message received ${message}`)
  }

})()
```

edit: oh, and `ws` and `http` are different protocols. you will need a different server to serve your http files